# How to get newly inserted records in SQL Server per day

Tags: sql-server

I am using a SQL Server database, and I need to get the total number of newly inserted records per day, per week, per month, and per year separately. I have a column in my SQL Server database that records the date and time (the data type is `datetime`).

I used the following code to get the daily records but doesn't work

SQL:

```
select count(*) 
from dbo.Firsttimer 
where (Signed_in) = date(date_sub(now());
```

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: Well, for starters, SQL Server has no functions called date, date_sub() or now().  What are they supposed to do?

Comment: First, what do you mean my *"doesn't work"*? Second, `date_sub` is a `mysql` function, for `sql server` try `dateadd` instead. Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15619659/4730201

Comment: Okay. Please can you brief me on how to do that ?

Comment: Please spend some time reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and working through the examples there.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you get the current `DateTime` value using the built in `GetDate()` method.

So to get all the records that have today's date in a specific `DateTime` column you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
DECLARE @ToDate date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FromDate)

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.Firsttimer 
WHERE [Signed_in] >= @FromDate
AND [Signed_in] < @ToDate
```

To get the first and last day of the week you can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267126/how-do-you-get-the-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-week-number-in-sql),
first day and last day of the month on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916398/sql-server-2005-get-first-and-last-date-for-any-month-in-any-year),
and first and last day of the year on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437362/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-date-of-the-current-year)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use conditional aggregation, i.e. a `count(case...)`, along with the `getdate()` and `dateadd()` functions.

```
select
    Today = cast(getdate() as date)
    ,TodayCount = count(case when cast(Signed_in as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then Signed_in)
    ,RollingWeekCount = count(case when cast(Signed_in as date) >= dateadd(day,-7,cast(getdate() as date)) then Signed_in)
    ,Rolling30Days = count(case when cast(Signed_in as date) >= dateadd(day,-30,cast(getdate() as date)) then Signed_in)
    ,Rolling365Days = count(case when cast(Signed_in as date) >= dateadd(day,-365,cast(getdate() as date)) then Signed_in)
from
    YourTable
```

If you wanted this split out for each week, each month, each year... then that's best handled another way. However you didn't specify this so I provided a rolling method.